# IIS7 - how to configure server to serve large (GBs) files?

Tags: iis-7, http, files

I wanted to download some backups (about 4..5Gb in size) via HTTP and was surprised that IIS7 didn't allowed me to do so. The attempt was seemingly blocked - got a 404 page.

Where should I go in the IIS Management console to allow such downloads?

Answer (score 7):

Configure the `maxRequestEntityAllowed` property in the asp limits sections of the web configuration:

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp/limits

If you have the Request Filtering feature installed and enabled, you should also set the "**Maximum allows content length**" value in IIS Manager -> Features -> Request Filtering -> Edit Feature settings

Comment: "Maximum allows content length" is 4294967295 bytes (exactly 4 Gb) on that system. Same for maxRequestEntityAllowed. (Request? not Response? how it should work?)

Comment: If you set the limits to the maximum values, IIS will interpret them as "unlimited", at least that's how it worked in the IIS6 metabase. 

Please be aware that IE, prior to version 8 has Content-Length limits of 4GB (IE7) and 2GB (IE6)

Comment: @MathiasRJessen can you find me a direct proof of the "unlimited" claim? After short googling, I found some results on this value becoming "unlimited" in other settings, but found no clear results for the following query: ` "Maximum allows content length"|maxallowedcontentlength 4294967295 unlimited  `

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524953%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Is installing ASP.NET feature required just to serve large files?